# How do I read this cryptocompare table?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate, exchange-fees

in the [Cryptocompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/exchanges/bitstamp/overview) table I don't understand what the columns mean, e.g. there is Price, "Open 24H", "Range 24H", etc... Does anyone know what the different columns mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24H means 24-hours period.

Open 24H:
The price of the first transaction 24 hours ago.

Range 24H:
H - High: Highest price reached.
L - Low: Lowest price reached

Last Trade:
Value of the last transaction that took place.

Volume 24H:
The amount of BTC that change hands.

Change 24H:
Price and % change during the past 24 hours.